# Is there a difference between 'futari' and 'futari-domo'?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

What is the difference between 'futari' and 'futari-domo'?

Also, is 二人共 the correct way to write 'futari-domo'?

Comment: 「二人とも」は副詞的に使えますね。

Comment: ... and 「～共」 is usually read ども when added to a (pro)noun as a humble/pejorative plural suffix (eg. [手前]{てまえ}ども、[私]{わたくし}ども、人間ども、虫けらども、[兵]{つわもの}ども、[野郎]{やろう}ども...) and とも when following 「number + counter」meaning "both/all" (eg. ２人とも、２つとも、３匹とも、３回とも、４本とも...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo Hamsteriffic, you probably mean futari-**T**omo.

The difference is as follows:

> 二人 ⇒ two people.
>
> 二人共 ⇒ both people.

Answer (score 4):

“二人” means *two persons*, e.g. 二人で合唱する ‐ Two (people) sing a duet.

“二人とも” means *both of the two*, or *two of them together*, e.g. 彼は兄弟二人とも東大出身である ‐ Both he and his brother graduated from Tokyo University.

“二人共” can also be written “二人とも”, and should be pronounced “Hutari **t**omo,” not “Hutari domo.”

When we say 共々, e.g. “夫婦共々”元気に過ごしています ‐ "We, as a couple, are faring well," it should be pronounced “Huu-hu tomo**d**omo.”